# Session Value not retained sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have recently allocated a work of letting employees filled their entries for a month.
I have a grid having 30,31,27,28 column based on month selected. User adds a row,selects a task from grid view row drop-down and fills his time sheet for the particular day of the selected month.
 On page load if user has previously submitted some entries i take those entries in a data table,store the datatable in session using Session["TimeSheet"]=data table name and bind the data table with the grid.If its for the first time then also a blank datatable with default schema is created and it is binded to the session using the same Session["TimeSheet"]=data table name. Thus it is guaranteed that Session variable will have some data table stored.

On every add button click i fetch data table from session variable,add a new row in the data table and bind the grid.But to my badluck sometime my add button gets Session["TimeSheet"] as null and Sometimes not.

But if i'm guranteed to have stored datatable in Session how come it is coming null sometimes in Session Variable. I have used break point and found that Session variable is always set on page load. But why on add button click it is not working.....I have seen other stackoverflow tags also they said to check webgarden,WebFarm,Application domain recycling. But as if now its not even working in default VS development server.

Please help. I'm stuck in this problem from last 3 days......

Comment: Have you placed this check if(!IsPostBack) in page loadd ?

Comment: please add your code with your question.

Comment: have you tried setting this / initializing this initially in the `Global.asax` file in the `protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` also use `HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeSheet"]` initialize that to string.Empty or some other value in the said method above..

Comment: also get out of that ignorant frame of mind meaning `Thus it is guaranteed` `NOTHING is GUARANTEED`

Comment: I have initialise the session in global.asax.cs in Session_Start...STill the problem persists

Comment: DJ KRAZE with all due respect how does it matter i'm anyhow setting Session value to null in PageLoad !ISPostback

Comment: Mairaj Ahmad Sir.....IYes i used !IsPostback and i checked there if session is not null set it to null

Answer (score 0):

```
private object obj = null;
private object mySession
{
    get
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            obj = new object();        //OR
            obj = Session["Session"];
            //Initialise your object with default value
        }
        return obj;
    }
    set
    {
        obj = value;
    }
}
```

Use mySession varibale in your code where you required

```
DataSet ds = mySession as DataSet;
//as you required you can typecast
```